Expectation of a Random Variable in Probability.
When I first learned about expectation in probability, I understood it through the lens of a game. For example, if we're tossing a coin and earn $\$10$ for heads and $\$20$ for tails, the expected value of this game is $\$15$. This means I would be willing to pay any amount less than $15 to play this game, as that's what I expect to win on average.
However, consider a different game where you toss a coin repeatedly until you get tails, and if tails occurs on the nth toss, you win 2^n dollars. The expected value of this game is infinite, which suggests that, theoretically, you should be willing to pay any finite amount to play.
But does this mean you should be willing to pay any amount of money to play this game?

This is widely discussed, often under the name St. Petersburg Paradox.  But, yes.  Expected value is only  a proxy for the attractiveness of a game,  it is not equivalent to it.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Expectation can be infinite as in your example, or even undefined.

Then how should I interpret Expected value as?

You don't need infinities to realize that Expectation is an incomplete proxy (at best).  Consider any game with a "lottery ticket" like payout.  Something which only pays out with an absurdly low probability, but which pays out enough in that unlikely scenario to make the expectation attractive.

I think I've got it now. Thanks for your help!

As an illustration of an issue with the St Petersburg's game (apart for the need for  the bank to have unlimited funds to pay your prizes), see an earlier question (with prizes of $$2^{n-1}$, so half your prizes):  if you start with $$100$ and pay $$10$ to play each time, the probability you eventually run out of money is about $99.979%$.
